# Springboot - Executing Fat Jar

Tags: spring-boot

I have a springboot application which creates a JAR artifact using maven build. I understand that we can execute this jar from command line by going into target folder and executing appropriate command but what I want to know that how can I export this jar to a different machine(Unix Box) and execute the jar?

Comment: i am not sure i understand your question. I guess you have to deploy your jar to your artifactory, then use your CI/CD server to have it copied from nexus to your machine where you have created lets say a a unix service that runs the command 'java -jar your-app.jar'

Comment: You could just copy over your jar file to the Unix box e.g scp your_username@remotehost:foobar.jar /some/local/directory

Comment: Yes. I can copy over my jar but then how do I execute? If I run java -jar app.jar, it gives me java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for the main class.

Comment: Can you post the pom of your application and the Application class please (the one annotated with @SpringbootApplication)

Comment: How did you build your jar file?

Comment: I have a multi module maven project. I built my jar file by running mvn clean package. I tried to build a war file (by not including tomcat dependency) and then deploy the same in a tomcat container in a unix box. It works fine.  What I want to try though is build an executable jar file, copy the jar to a unix location and from there execute java -jar .